# FullCalender:- On load events time is not correct

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, fullcalendar

On loading/fetching events, its adds 9 minutes extra in the actual time.

In the database this is **2016-09-22 08:00:00** but on calendar this is **2016-09-22 08:09:00).**

We are using below code for setting parameters:-

```
 $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        events: json_events,           
        utc: true,
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,agendaWeek'
        },
        defaultView: 'month',
        editable: true,
        droppable: true,
        slotDuration: '01:00:00', //'00:30:00' for 30 minutes
        displayEventTime: true,
        axisFormat: 'HH:mm',
        timeFormat: 'hh:mm',
        allDaySlot: false,      
        timezone: 'Asia/Kolkata',
});
```

Comment: Please provide the code you have tried and that is not working.

Comment: Hi peter, Can you please suggest on this

Answer (score 0):

I just check your code this is fine. I think you are doing some customization in the **eventRender** function.

If you are using format() function then please use like below:-

```
event.start.format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss")
```

I am sure in your case you are using like below:-

```
event.start.format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS")
```

Please tell me if this helps :)